# I'm not getting any output from this code in the screen

Tags: c++

i was trying to solve this question and i am not getting any output on the screen after giving input

Given an array of integers representing measurements in inches, write a program to calculate the total measurements

in feet. Ignore the measurements those are less than a feet (e.g. 10)

Example

Finding the total measurements in feet from a list of 5 numbers

Input:-

input 1:

5

input 2:

18 11 27 12 14

Output :-

5

Explanation

The first parameter (5) is the size of the array Next is an array of measurements in inches. The total number of teeth is 5 which is calculated as under

18 -> 1

11-> 0

27 -> 2

12 -> 1

14-> 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int total = 0;
int main()
{
int arr[1000];
//int arr1[1000];
int size;

cin >> size;
int x;

for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
    x = arr[i] / 12;
    total = x + total;
    x = 0;
}

cout << total;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `arr`, all you need is a single `int` variable.

Comment: Also note that your loop requires `size + 1` inputs.

Comment: Can you recheck the example? Why are there 6 numbers as input, but it should be 5. What is the 2 in this example?

Comment: yeah i have corrected the example thank you for pointing that , cheers

Comment: works as expected for me: http://cpp.sh/2db3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of times you are taking the input is one more than size. Also x=0 is redundant.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int total = 0;
int main()
{
int arr[1000];
//int arr1[1000];
int size;

cin >> size;
int x;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
    x = arr[i] / 12;
    total = x + total;
    //x = 0; Not required
}

cout << total;
return 0;
}
```